# http to https changing for Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: http, url, amazon-s3, https

My files in my s3 bucket is now visible as 
http://mybucket.s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/banner/573d3812d1d0a.jpeg

I would like to change as 
https://mybucket.s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/banner/573d3812d1d0a.jpeg

How can I change my bucket links http:// to https:// ?

Answer (score 0):

This should help

[Using an HTTPS Connection to Access Your Objects](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/SecureConnections.html)

Good Luck!!